# Azure Kubernetes Container Logs to Event Hub

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-eventhub

How to logs (stdout / stderr) from all container pods azure Kubernetes to the event hub.
I can able to see all logs by Log Analytics workspaces >> Logs using an Azure query language.

I want to send all logs to the event hub.

Can anyone suggest on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily forward container logs to Event Hubs via Fluent-Bit's Kafka output.

Here is Fluent-Bit documentation for Kafka - https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/kafka

And here is Kafka client integration with Event Hubs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me using fluentbit kafka output to Azure EventHub

*td-agent-bit.conf*

```
[INPUT]
  Name                tail
  Path                xxx.log
  Refresh_Interval    10

[OUTPUT]
  Name        kafka
  Match       *
  brokers     xxx.xxx.windows.net:9093
  topics      xxx
  rdkafka.security.protocol   SASL_SSL
  rdkafka.sasl.username       $ConnectionString
  rdkafka.sasl.password       Endpoint=sb://xxx.xxx.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxx;SharedAccessKey=xxx
  rdkafka.sasl.mechanism      PLAIN

[OUTPUT]
  name  stdout
  match *
```

Inside docker container (MUST HAVE or broker down/ssl fail)

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  fluent-bit:
    image: fluent/fluent-bit:1.6.2
    container_name: fluentbit
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./td-agent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
      - ./xxx.log:/fluent-bit/etc/xxx.log:ro
```